# How do I get the PDFPage when PDFViewPageChanged is tried on a PDFView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, pdfkit

The code bellow triggers every time the page is changed by the user on a PDFView. However, I don't know how to access the PDFPage object that is associated with this Notification.

My goal is to display a Text on the screen that will keep track of the current page (example: "Page 1 of 10"). Perhaps, there is a different way of achieving this same goal, and I am open to suggestions.

```
var body: some View {
     PDFKitView(url: documentUrl)
          .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .PDFViewPageChanged)) { obj in
               //????
          }

     [...]
```